# SQLAlchemy / Flask - Get number of rows in relationship table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, graphene-python, graphene-sqlalchemy

Here's my scenario. I have a table of `Books` each book has a table of `Questions` and each question has a table of `Answers`.

What I want to do is *efficiently* get the **amount** of answers for a given list of `Question.id`. Example:

```
# 6,000 Question.id's for Book.id == 1
questions = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ..., 6000]
```

Here's what I'm doing and its proving to be very very inefficient:

```
# This takes a couple minutes for it to finish
count = 0
query = QuestionModel.query.filter(QuestionModel.id.in_(questions)).all()

for q in query:
  count += len(list(q.Answers))

# count = 3456
```

I'm assuming this is so slow because `q.Answers` is actually getting populated with data.

Here are my models:

```
class BookModel(db.base):
    __tablename__ = 'books_book'
    __table_args__ = {
        'autoload': True,
        'extend_existing': True,
        'autoload_with': db.instance.engine,
    }
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    Chapters = relationship(ChapterModel)
    QuestionMeta = relationship(QuestionMetaModel)

class QuestionMetaModel(db.base):
    __tablename__ = 'questions_questionmeta'
    __table_args__ = {
        'autoload': True,
        'extend_existing': True,
        'autoload_with': db.instance.engine,
    }
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    question_id = Column(ForeignKey('questions_question.id'))
    book_id = Column(ForeignKey('books_book.id'))
    chapter_id = Column(ForeignKey('books_chapter.id'))

class QuestionModel(db.base):
    __tablename__ = 'questions_question'
    __table_args__ = {
        'autoload': True,
        'extend_existing': True,
        'autoload_with': db.instance.engine,
    }
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    Answers = relationship(AnswerModel)

class AnswerModel(db.base):
    __tablename__ = 'answers_answer'
    __table_args__ = {
        'autoload': True,
        'extend_existing': True,
        'autoload_with': db.instance.engine,
    }
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    question_id = Column(ForeignKey('questions_question.id'))
```

**Question:** All I want is the **amount** of entries in `QuestionModel.Answers` not the actual data itself. How would I accomplish this, so it doesn't take 2 minutes for one `Book.id`? Grabbing the `Question.id` for each book is fast, but grabbing the amount of answers for each `Question.id` is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

Perform a `join` across `BookModel`, `QuestionModel`, and `AnswerModel` and use SQLAlchemy `func.count`.

```
from sqlalchemy import func

count_query = (session.query(BookModel, QuestionModel, AnswerModel, func.count(AnswerModel.id))
    .select_from(AnswerModel)
    .join(QuestionModel)
    .join(BookModel)
    .group_by(BookModel)
)
```

Comment: Hi I updated my question to include a couple other models. How would it work in this case? Thanks!

Comment: While selecting nonaggregate columns that are not in the group by list is supported by some DBMS, it's usually not such a great feature due to more or less nondeterministic results.